# Bootstrap Dropdown.js: Which HTML attributes are really necessary? (data-target, role, aria...)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, wai-aria

We use the [Dropdown.js of Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).

As we don't use Bootstrap for any other part of our application, we don't use aria attributes in general, so now we are unsure, which attributes we can strip out of the copy&pasted HTML structure.

In my opinion, we only need this:

```html
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Dropdown</a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
  <li><a...>...</a></li>
</ul>
```

But a co-developer thinks, we also need `data-target='#'` and `role='button/menu'`, and even `aria-labelledby=...` stuff. Is this right? We really only want the dropdown functionality, no additional accessibility related stuff.

Thanks for information.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding `<a>` and `aria-labelledby` see [**w3.org**](http://rawgithub.com/w3c/aria-in-html/master/index.html#aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby)

> [..] Currently aria-labelledby and aria-describedby are more robustly
>   supported for associating text content to a subset of interactive
>   content elements. **As of this writing they do not work correctly on
>   links** [EDITOR: add blocking bug link?], support on embedded content is
>   unknown, but can be safely used on form controls including the many
>   input types.

To make sense there also should be an element `aria-labelledby` adresses, like

```
<a href="#" aria-labelledby="meaningless">link</a>
<span id="meaningless">click here</span>
```

Obviously `<a>`-tags is interactive but have their own label.

---

As for `role="button/menu"`, cannot find the precise documentation, but I do not believe it is legal to "invent" new role types, like `button/menu`. Only [**the standard roles**](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles#role_definitions) is legal. How should a reader parse button/menu? Even if it split, the two roles are not compatible. See this [**w3 recommendation table**](http://rawgithub.com/w3c/aria-in-html/master/index.html#recommendations-table) for how and when to use the role attribute under different circumstances.

---

My personal conclusion : Totally agree with you, Joshua Muheim - `role='button/menu'` and `aria-labelledby=` is waste of time in that particular context.